# Data Profiling using PostgreSQL Function

Tags: postgresql, function, plpgsql

I am trying to do some data profiling using Postgres function. I have tried the below function which results in an error. As I am new to database functions, procedures etc.. I am finding difficult in fixing this issue.

**Actual Work:**

I want to loop through all columns in a table and perform data profiling i.e. Count,  count distinct, nulls, not nulls for character columns. Min, Max for Numeric & date columns. Please assist

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION data_profiling (TABLE_VALUE VARCHAR) 
 RETURNS TABLE (
 col_value VARCHAR,
 DISTINCT_COUNT INT
) 
AS $$
DECLARE 
    var_c Varchar;

BEGIN
   FOR var_c IN(SELECT c.column_name,c.table_name
        FROM information_schema.columns c
        WHERE lower(c.table_name) = TABLE_VALUE)  
     LOOP
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'SELECT ' || var_c ||' as col_name, count(distinct ' || var_c ||') as distinct_count
FROM ' || TABLE_VALUE || ' group by ' || var_c;
            END LOOP;
END; $$ 
 LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

**Error:**

```
ERROR:  structure of query does not match function result type
DETAIL:  Returned type character(50) does not match expected type character varying in column 1.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function data_profiling(character varying) line 10 at RETURN QUERY
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cursor returns a *record* not a varchar, you need to change your declaration to:

```
var_c record;
```

The record will have as many fields as you include columns in your select list, each one can be referenced through the column's name. It's also better to use the `format()` function to generate the dynamic SQL.

`count()` also returns a `bigint` not an `int`. You also need to cast the column you select to `varchar` otherwise you can't return e.g. an integer value as the first column.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION data_profiling (table_value varchar) 
  RETURNS TABLE (col_value varchar, distinct_count bigint)
AS 
$$
DECLARE 
    var_c record;
BEGIN
   FOR var_c IN (SELECT c.table_schema, c.column_name,c.table_name
                 FROM information_schema.columns c
                 WHERE lower(c.table_name) = TABLE_VALUE
                   and c.table_schema = 'public')  
   LOOP
       RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 
        format('SELECT %I::varchar, count(distinct %I) FROM %I.%I group by %I', 
               var_c.column_name, var_c.column_name, var_c.table_schema, var_c.table_name, var_c.column_name);
   END LOOP;
END; $$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The placeholder `%I` (a capital `i`) will take care of properly quoting the column or table name if necessary. You should also make sure you include the schema name.

The language name is an identifier, don't put it in single quotes.

You also don't need to specify a column alias in the generated SQL, as the names of the output columns are defined by the `returns table (..)` part. That makes the code a bit easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

You need declare the length for your return table

```
RETURNS TABLE (
   col_value VARCHAR(8000),
   DISTINCT_COUNT INT
```

Comment: No, that's not necessary.